# In 'Two Tribes' of Frankie goes to Hollywood, is it a 'point' or 'money' that you can score? Do they actually say 'let's go to war'?

Tags: lyrics

The anti-war song 'Two Tribes' from Frankie goes to Hollywood, with their striking music-video (released in 1984), got my attention again.
Although the video was banned by the BBC at the time, the clip can now be found on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/pO1HC8pHZw0).

But now being able to lookup the lyric on several websites, I noticed a very different text in the lyric that I can remember (and still hear, when watching the video).

For example, [Google/LyricFind](https://www.google.com/search?q=two+tribes+frankie+goes+to+hollywood+lyrics) got the following text:

```
When two tribes go to war
A point is all you can score
(Storm them all, storm them all)
```

On another website [azlyrics](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/frankiegoestohollywood/twotribes.html):

```
When two tribes go to war
A point is all that you can score
Score no more! Score no more!
```

But what I actually hear is:

```
When two tribes go to war
Money is all that you can score
(let's got to war, let's got to war)
```

Which sounds like a very plausible lyrics, because money is indeed the only thing that you can score (on the expense of all other things, ofcourse).

Do other people also hear this? Or is it just me?

Comment: The word used is, "one is all that you can score"... as in "one nil" in football.

Comment: I always thought it was "moneys all that you can score"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here, because when it was a fresh single I listened to on radio/TV* at the time, I thought it was 'Let's go to war' too… but it's not.

> When two tribes go to war
> A point is all that you can score
> Score no more! Score no more!

There are some amusing variations on the lyrics across the interwebz;)
'A point' and 'score no more' are easiest to hear in the drop section of what as a Brit I'd call the 'regular radio mix' [idk its official title, but your YT/Vevo link feels like the one].
If you dig out the otherwise abysmal 'Intermission Legend Mix' it's clearer still. The iTunes/Music demo has it at about 40 seconds [assuming everybody hears the same excerpt]

Ah… late edit - I found the full version of the Intermission Legend Mix on YT, official band/Universal channel. It opens with a quiet drop section you can hear it really clearly… [& it saves you having to listen to the whole thing - the instrumentation isn't even in tune with the vocals, so it hurts, a lot:\

*[& I'm sure I saw the video on TOTP at the time… because where else would you see it unless you stayed up all night to watch MTV - which as far as I recall ran on Ch4 after midnight, along with Music Box. It was to be another 10 years before I had cable, by which time I'd completely given up on MTV.]

…and before it raises another question… it's black *gas*.